# Completely separate full screen OpenGL context on second monitor

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, opengl

For a 3D scanner implementation I need to precisely control the output of a projector connected as a second monitor to my graphics card. I would need to issue OpenGL commands in a full screen context on this second monitor using a second X server instance. I am on Ubuntu 13.04 with a Dell Precision T3600 Workstation containing a AMD V7900 GPU.

How do I get one X server with Unity on the main screen and a second X server instance for the projector which contains only a fullscreen OpenGL context?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I came up with a solution, albeit it is a bit trickery.
I have configured my graphics driver for a multi display setup. This way each "monitor" is represented as a separate X screen. Ubuntu Unity does not play nicely with this, as it currently expects a XrandR setup with a single virtual screen. 
However, by erasing the relative screen location information from my xorg.conf, Unity is ignoring the second screen altogether. Now, I can create a fullscreen OpenGL context on the second X screen without any interference from the OS.
The top of my xorg.conf looks like this:

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "amdcccle Layout"
    Screen      0  "amdcccle-Screen[5]-0" 0 0
    Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[5]-1"
EndSection

In the old-style multi-screen setup, the second screen would have position specifiers (e.g. 1920 0 or "Right of Screen 0"). By removing them, the second screen is ignored.